# Loop until any of the elements of a std::vector is not encountered

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, vector

I am trrying to make a basic parser for c++ code that extracts information about classes from the input code. For this I have a method that looks for data members starting from an iterator position until it encounters certain strings like "public", "protected", "};". The strings are passed in a vector because I have to use the function for other breakpoints too and due to this the number of strings cant be fixed. How can I  get the elements of a vector inside the condition of a loop when I dont know at what subscript to stop?
It looks something like this:

```
while(a != vect[0] && a != vect[1] .... && a != vect[END VALUE]) {
    //loop body
}
```

Where END VALUE could be anything.

Is this possible?
Hope i explained my query well. I am using iterators in code. Used subscripts only to explain my query.

Thanks!

Comment: `std::find` is your friend.

Comment: `std::vector::size()`?

Comment: @ZivS thought about it but again i'd have to iterate through the vector inside the loop condition.

Comment: *Why* do you have to iterate over the vector? Perhaps you need [`std::search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) instead of [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)? What is the actual *problem* you need to solve? What is the reason behind the loop?

Comment: @Some programmer dude i have updated the question.

Comment: You are aware that your `while` condition doesn't have to be just plain comparisons, right? It's just a boolean expression. Which can always be a function call that returns `bool`, where you pass in a reference to the vector, and the value, and have a completely independent C++ function iterate over the vector and check if it contains a value, and returns either true or false, depending upon whether the value exists in the vector.

Comment: got the solution. Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: @Hassaan When you arrive at a solution that wasn't in an answer, you should write an answer and tell us what that solution was. [Just saying "got the solution" does not help anybody](https://xkcd.com/979/).

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, you are worried "i'd have to iterate through the vector inside the loop condition", however *any* implementation will have to go through each element to verify it can continue.

Your loop condition can be expressed as "stop if we find `a` in `vect`", and we can see that there is a nice [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) already in `<algorithm>`. `std::find` returns an iterator pointing to where it found the element, or `end` if it didn't find it.

```
while(std::find(vect.begin(), vect.end(), a) == vect.end()) {
    //loop body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's checking that an element doesn't exist between a `start` position and a `finish` position, you could use:

```
bool not_present(size_t start, size_t finish, value_type value, const ContainerType& vect)
{
    for (size_t i = start; i <= finish; ++i)
    {
        if (value == vect[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why would you not use `find` for this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OP has an index into a `vector` for a finish position (I generalized a start position), so seemed more straightforward to proceed this way

Comment: `std::find(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + N, value) == vec.end()`?

Comment: Also your version uses a fully closed range which is not idiomatic!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the OP uses fully closed ranges.

Comment: I realise that but same comment to them :P A re-usable function like this shouldn't

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sure and using all caps in a variable name is far from acceptable in industrial grade code but given we're dealing with teaching the fundamental concept of collapsing `n` comparisons down into a loop I thought small steps were preferable.

Comment: Don't entirely disagree. Just noting!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was pretty simple though. My mind was just stuck up at "iterate through vector in loop condition" that was the culprit.

This is what I did:

```
bool check(const vector<string>& flags, const 
vector<string>::iterator& pos/*iterator for the vector containing code*/)

{
     for(auto it = flags.begin(); it != flags.end(); it++)
           {
               if(*pos == *it) return true;
           }
     return false;
}
```